# AEM 6.3 - Migrate Felix to OSGi annotations: How to deal with propertyPrivate?

Tags: spring, annotations, osgi, aem, apache-felix

I'm migrating an AEM 6.1 application to AEM 6.3. Since Felix annotations (org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.*) are deprecated, I decided to migrate my components to the OSGi annotations (org.osgi.service.component.annotations.*).

Once I figured out how it works, it is pretty easy. But there is one case I don't know how to handle: Properties with *propertyPriavte = true*.

The old implementation looks like this:

```
@Component(metatype = true)
@Service(Servlet.class)
@Properties({
        @Property(name = "sling.servlet.selectors", value = "overlay", propertyPrivate = true),
})
public class OverlayServletImpl extends OverlayServlet {
...
}
```

The property *sling.servlet.selectors* would not be configurable in the Configuration Manager at the AEM console, but it would be configurable due to a config file, right? So, I still need to define this property.

For other properties I changed my implementation like this:

```
// OverlayServletImpl
@Component(
        service = Servlet.class,
        configurationPid = "my.package.path.OverlayServletImpl"
)
@Designate(
        ocd = OverlayServletImplConfiguration.class
)
public class OverlayServletImpl extends OverlayServlet {
...
}

// Configuration
@ObjectClassDefinition(name = "Overlay Servlet")
public @interface OverlayServletImplConfiguration {

    String sling_servlet_selectors() default "overlay";
...
}
```

Now, I have the property *sling.servlet.selectors*, but it is also available in Configuration Manager and it'S value can be changed there. But I don't want that.

How can I do that? Is this possible with the OSGi annotations?

Thank you and best regards!

Comment: Do you have any documentation related to the OSGI annotations migration? I am also migrating from AEM6.1 to 6.3.. Is it necessary to migrate them?

Comment: Hello!
The Felix annotations are deprecated, but they still work in AEM 6.3. That means it is not necessary to migrate them yet, but it will be in future versions of AEM.
As documentation, I recommend the following page [OFFICIAL OSGI DECLARATIVE SERVICES ANNOTATIONS IN AEM](http://www.nateyolles.com/blog/2017/05/osgi-declarative-services-annotations-in-aem). There is also an link to a GitHub project, which shows how one and so same service has to be implemented with Felix annotations and the official OSGi annotations. That helped me a lot for the migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this might be possible if you use the `@Component` annotation to specify your private properties.

```
@Component(service = Servlet.class,
  property = 
  { SLING_SERVLET_RESOURCE_TYPES + "=aemhtlexamples/structure/page",
    SLING_SERVLET_METHODS + "=GET", 
    SLING_SERVLET_EXTENSIONS + "=html", 
    SLING_SERVLET_SELECTORS + "=hello" })
public class SimpleServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doGet(final SlingHttpServletRequest req, final SlingHttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    final Resource resource = req.getResource();
    resp.getOutputStream().println(resource.toString());
    resp.getOutputStream().println("This content is generated by the SimpleServlet");
  }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/heervisscher/htl-examples/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/examples/htl/core/servlets/SimpleServlet.java

Comment: Hello, sorry for my ate response, but I could not work on that topic and check if this works. @mickleroy's answer is correct and works.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible. Every property you define can be overridden by config.